# PDF Viewing on Forge Viewer fails displaying 2D model created by TEKLA - Failed to map font Arial

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am working on a PDF viewer starting from an example published by Michael Beale https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/fast-pdf-viewingmarkup-inside-forge-viewer.
It works great with a large number of documents of different kind.
My issue is that loading more than once many 2d models exported as PDF by TEKLA, the first time it works well but the following fails showing on console an error:

```
font-engine.js:51 Failed to map font Arial
value @ font-engine.js:51
value @ font-engine.js:59
value @ LmvCanvasContext.js:594
paintChar @ pdf.js:11506
showText @ pdf.js:11635
executeOperatorList @ pdf.js:11037
(anonymous) @ pdf.js:9541
_next @ pdf.js:9537
(anonymous) @ pdf.js:9528
requestAnimationFrame (async)
_scheduleNext @ pdf.js:9527
_continue @ pdf.js:9520
operatorListChanged @ pdf.js:9510
_renderPageChunk @ pdf.js:8503
(anonymous) @ pdf.js:9026
_onComObjOnMessage @ pdf.js:12705
path2d.js:676 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'triangulationFailed' of null
    at d.fill (path2d.js:676)
    at e.value (LmvCanvasContext.js:531)
    at e.value (LmvCanvasContext.js:595)
    at e.paintChar (pdf.js:11506)
    at e.showText (pdf.js:11635)
    at executeOperatorList (pdf.js:11037)
    at pdf.js:9541
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at t._next (pdf.js:9537)
    at pdf.js:9528
```

This is the code fragment:

```
function initializeViewer(pdf) {
    if (viewer) {
      console.log('loading');
      viewer.impl.unloadCurrentModel()
      if (markup) 
        markup.hide();
      viewer.loadModel(pdf, viewer);
      return;
    }

    var options = {
        env: "Local",
        useConsolidation: true,
        useADP: false,
    }

    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
      viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'));
      viewer.setTheme("light-theme");
      viewer.start();
      if (!pdf) return;


      viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.PDF').then( () => {
            viewer.loadModel(pdf, viewer);
            viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore")
            viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui")
      });
    });
```

You can find some PDF file here [github](https://github.com/cosgab/viewer2dpdf)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Viewer v6.5 and was unable to reproduce the issues unfortunately - see live sample [here](https://dukedhx.github.io/Forge-Workshop/sb233.html).

The only warnings I got was about unsolvable font paths:

> Warning: getPathGenerator - ignoring character: "Error: Requesting object that isn't resolved yet Helvetica_path_g".

**EDIT:**

To load another:

```
viewer.finish(); 
Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.unregisterExtension('Autodesk.PDF');

viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(myViewerDiv);
...//reinitialize and load the PDF again
```

Agree however this should be handled more gracefully so you can go on to load another PDF straight away so let's wait for our Engineering to get back. In the meantime you can use what I proposed as a workaround for now.

Comment: Hi Bryan, you have to load the document twice on the same viewer in order to get the error. The first time the rendering if fast and good. The second time, after unloaded the previous document and loaded the new one, you can have a partial rendering or a complete hang.

Comment: See my edit - you will need to unload the extension

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that's definitely a bug!

ok, so I added your two PDF's to the sample page (bug1.pdf and bug2.pdf)

demo: https://wallabyway.github.io/offline-pdf-markup/

#### Why it breaks...

When loading a second PDF, my code tear's down the previous PDF, but it looks like it leaves something behind in memory.

I tried three tear down techniques...

1. unloadModel()
2. viewer.tearDown()
3. completely initializing the viewer from scratch (removing lines 39-46)

but... "None of these worked" !!!

source code: https://github.com/wallabyway/offline-pdf-markup

So...

looking at the console errors, it looks like those drawings have some complex path overlaps, which are too tricky for the "Poly2Tri" library, causing it to fail.  Unfortunately, it then leaves something behind in memory and doesn't load correctly on subsequent load attempts.

I've logged a bug (LMV-4525)

Comment: Better to call `finish` than `tearDown` directly - `finish` is officially documented while `tearDown` is not. And I'd put this in a comment instead of an answer if I were you coz it doesn't really answer anything...